# Limit of a sequence involving absolute value and subsequences

Tags: real-analysis, limits, proof-explanation

So I have the following question:

Suppose $lim|X_n|$ =3 but $X_n$ does not have a convergent sub-sequence with limit 3.

Prove $limX_n=-3$.

Here is my attempt:

1. $lim|X_n| =3$ so ${|X_n|}$ is bounded by the Boundedness Theorem. This implies ${X_n}$ is also bounded.
2. by properties of absolute value  $-|a|\le a \le |a|$ so $-|X_n|\le X_n \le |X_n|$
3. taking the limit of inequality yields $-3 \le limX_n \le 3$
4. Suppose $limX_n$ = 3 contradiction because if $limX_n=x$ then all ${X_{n_k}}$ also converge to x and it is stated in the problem that there is no subsequence with limit 3.
5. Suppose $-3 \lt limX_n \lt 3$ which implies that $|limX_n|\lt3$ but $|limX_n|=lim|X_n|\lt3$ which is also  contradiction because if $limX_n=x$ then $lim|X_n|=|X_n|$ and we know $lim|X_n|=3$
6. Thus $limX_n=3$

turned this in a few days ago and teacher was ok with it I just forgot to update post sorry

Comment: "4. Because $lim|X_n|=3$ because if  $limX_n=3$ or $limX_n=-3$" This is of course the crucial step and it is most unclear. What do you mean there?

Comment: i meant Because $lim|X_n|=3$
 then 
 $limX_n=3$ or $limX_n=-3$ it has been edited to reflect such

Comment: And this is quite wrong: consider for example $X_n=3(-1)^n$ then $\lim|X_n|=3$ but $(X_n)$ diverges hence $\lim X_n=3$ and $\lim X_n=-3$ are both false.

Comment: alrighty well i got stuff to do in RL atm so I will ponder this....if you have any thoughts on what I should do feel free to pass them along and I will post  revisions later

Comment: Looks good to me.

Comment: @Did sorry but your counterexample does not work as $X_n=3(-1)^n$ would have a convergent subsequence of 3 which is contradicting the given information of the problem

Comment: Yes the counterexample works perfectly, thank you, to show that $\lim|X_n|=3$ does not imply that either $\lim X_n=3$ or that $\lim X_n=-3$. This simple remark kills your 4. as it was written at the time. In the current version, it kills your 2. Looking at the revisions of your post, one can see that during 16 minutes, you seemed to realize that $\lim|X_n|=3$ implies that either $\lim X_n=3$ or that $\lim X_n=-3$ **or that $(X_n)$ does not converge**. Why did you delete this good idea afterwards?

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net "Looks good to me." Seriously?

Comment: @Did The issue is that there has been too many versions of the answer.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net True (although I am not sure the version at the moment you posted your comment was flawless).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can follow those directions :

- If $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \vert X_n \vert = 3$ then $(X_n)$ is bounded.
- As $(X_n)$ is bounded, it has at least a limit point.
- The only possible limit point is $3$.

Conclude.

Comment: its so easy now thanks a bunch!

Comment: so I have a question....what if $X_n=(-1)^n$ which does not converge but $|X_n|$ does converge. How do I get around that in the first step b/c once I know $X_n$ has a limit I have the rest done

Comment: You were also given that the sequence doesn't have a sub-sequence converging to $3$. $(-1)^n$ has a sub-sequence converging to $1$ and another one converging to $-1$.

Comment: please check out my attempt on my post as I just edited to reflect such

Answer (score 0):

Could we use the negation of the theorem: X = (xn ) be a bounded sequence of real numbers. Then we have
the property that every convergent subsequence of X converges to x. Then the sequence X
converges to x.
Then there exists a convergent subsequence of X does not convergent to x. Then the sequence X does not convergent to x. So lim(Xn) not equal to 3.
When xn>0, lim(xn)=3, when xn<=0, lim(-xn)=-lim(xn)=3  then  lim(xn)=-3. since lim(xn)not equal to 3, then xn not >0, then xn<=0, and lim(xn) =-3.